# Android Calling Multiple methods 1 by 1

Tags: android, function, methods, call

I have this function where it checks what are the choices of the users made.
So for example
there is a 4 choices:

1. InfoOfUp
2. InfoOfArt
3. InfoOfParish
4. InfoOfAteneo.

So when the user selects InfoOfUp and InfoOfArt then on the next activity, i will click a button that contains function : selected() it will check the items that was choosen by the user. if the user choose item InfoOfUp it will run a specific function and if the user choose item InfoOfArt it will also run a specific function

The problem is every item has it's own function and every item have progress dialog that marks if the function is already done or not.
So the user choose 2 items there's an error because there's 2 function being called up at the same time;

I want the function to be call 1by1 where the function waits to the other function to finish.

To avoid confusion, i call methods as function.

```
 public void selected() {

     if (InfoOfUp.select == 1) {
                if (ayala == 0) {
                    ayala();
                ayala = 1;
            } else if (ayala == 1) {

            }
        }

        if (InfoOfArt.select == 1) {
            if (art == 0) {
                ArtInIsland();

                art = 1;
            } else if (art == 1) {

            }
        }

        if (InfoOfParish.select == 1) {
            if (parish == 0) {
                parish();
                parish = 1;

            } else if (parish == 1) {

            }
        }


        if (InfoOfAteneo.select == 1) {

            if (ateneo == 0) {
                ateneogallery();
                ateneo = 1;
            } else if (ateneo == 1) {

            }

        }
```

Additionally, if the function calls, it will run an asynctask to get data.
here is my asynctask:

```
public class connectAsyncTask3 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private traffic traffic;
    private boolean displayDestinationDetails;
    String url;
    boolean launchDestination;

    connectAsyncTask3(String urlPass, traffic traffic, boolean displayDestinationDetails) {
        this.url = urlPass;
        this.traffic = traffic;
        this.displayDestinationDetails = displayDestinationDetails;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(traffic.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.hide();
        if (result != null) {
            Log.d("momo2", " : " + result);
            traffic.drawPath(result);
            speakOut();


        }

        if (displayDestinationDetails) {

            Intent i = new Intent(traffic.this, poppers.class);
            i.putExtra("currentMarker", traffic.markers.size());
            traffic.startActivity(i);


        }






    }
}
```

Comment: Make the method `synchronized` is not enough?

Comment: @j.e.gr i'm not familliar with synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Classic multi threading situation. 
Create two threads, each one in the method related, start them and use

> thread.join()
>   to begin second thread only after first finished.

[great example here](http://www.journaldev.com/1024/java-thread-join-example)

Comment: I don't know how your project is build to ensure you that the threads have to be in same method or not but take a look at the example I give you in the link to get a look and feel of how to implement multithreading with join(). 
But the main principle is to be aware that such situation has to be treated by threads and to let them run one by one